# ROS supported PCI/PCI express data acquisition (daq) card

Tags: ros, hardware

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All
I am trying to read 6 channel Analog Input signal via ROS. My plan is to find one ROS supported PCI/PCI express DAQ card and plug it into my desktop PC. Has anyone know this type DAQ? Certainly if you have better idea to read 6 channel AI, please also let me know. Thanks a lot.
Jayson

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11582/ros-supported-pci/pci-express-data-acquisition-(daq)-card/) by [jayson ding](https://answers.ros.org/users/492/jayson-ding/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2011-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Sensoray 626 http://www.sensoray.com/products/626.htm seems to meet your requirements.

I've successfully used it with Ubuntu/ROS in the past, some code for installing the drivers and library can be found at http://www.ros.org/wiki/sensoray626

---

Originally posted by [wmcmahan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37/wmcmahan/) with karma: 70 on 2011-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1